# minimum height of ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a page with a ListView.builder and when I resize the window the ListView shrinks as expected and the Items are scrollable.

But I want it only to shrink to a minimum height so that some items are always showing, but at the moment it continues to shrink until you can't see anything.

I have tried wrapping it in a ConstrainedBox but it doesn't change anything. Using the following the expected behaviour is the Space occupied by the list on the screen will shrink as the window is resized but stop shrinking when it is 200 high.

What have I missed?

Thanks

```
ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 200),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: controller.items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text(controller.items[index].title.value));
        }
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Container has a height and width which the list.builder can inherit

Comment: You have minWidth in your code. You should try minHeight if you want to constrain the height.

Comment: You are correct Golden Lion but I want it to use All available space but have a minimum height. I want a page overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstrainedBox to set minHeight and maxHeight also note shrink wrap

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 35.0,
    maxHeight: 160.0,
  ),

  child: new ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      new ListItem(),
      new ListItem(),
    ],

  ),
)
```